# Record limit to ingest from teradata to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, teradata, data-ingestion

I am ingesting 5 tables from teradata to Hadoop using jdbc connector. I have written configuration files for the same.

Four out of the 5 tables are able to ingest perfectly and the record count is also matching. One table is not getting ingested at all. The count of this table is 56 Million (largest in this set) , the ingestion runs upto some ~35 Million records and stops abruptly, no error msg. The table is not getting created in Hadoop even for that 35M records. This is my usual ingestion method and nothing could go wrong in this.

Can someone suggest if there is any limit to the number of records that can get ingested from Teradata to Hadoop ?

Comment: Not on Teradata side. I have been pulling 1B+ records from TD, no prob. I suspect your JVM may be running out of heap space if you retain your entire resultset in memory.

Comment: oh.. thanks .. let me check that